# JPEG Taking up ~20x Space as Expected

Tags: android, heap-dump, android-graphics

I use a jpeg in my Android App that takes up 1.6 MB on disk (on OSX). I noticed garbage collector warnings in the app logs, and took a heap dump in Android Studio. Out of a retained heap size of  36.5 MB, my home page fragment (this is the one with the jpeg) is taking up 36 MB.

I loaded the heap dump in Memory Analyzer Tool (MAT) and see a android.graphics.Bitmap taking up 36 MB of space in the heap. It's attribute view doesn't show the file name, but the dimensions match the 1.6 MB jpeg's dimensions.

[image: MAT General View]

[image: MAT Attribute View]

How would an image that takes up less than 2 MB on disk take up 36 MB on an Android app's heap?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPEG is a compressed image format. To render it, Android needs to decompress it.

Comment: ...and as CommonWare says, an image that is 4000x2250 at 4 bytes per pixel is 36MB. Makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Well as @CommonsWare pointed out, `bitmap` is being displayed not the compressed format, which in your case is `JPEG`.

But as to how to solve this evident problem; `bitmap down-sampling`, `bitmap configurations`, and `resizing` are valid options to decrease your `bitmap` size.

Nonetheless, managing your memory allocation is always a good idea. Specially something like `Managing Bitmap Memory` and `Caching Bitmaps`.

And that usually boils down to

```
1- Version(s) of Android you are targeting

2- Memory vs. Disk cache
```